# why isValidSignature is not in the gnosis safe contract?

Tags: ethers.js, gnosis-safe

I have a safe contract and I'm trying to sign message with it and verify it,

```
export async function createSafe() {
  const { daoMember1, daoMember2, daoMember3, daoMember4 } = await getAccounts()

  // Deploy Gnosis Safe master copy contract
  const masterCopyFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('GnosisSafe')
  const masterCopy = await masterCopyFactory.deploy()

  // Deploy Gnosis Safe proxy factory contract
  const proxyFactoryFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('GnosisSafeProxyFactory')
  const proxyFactory = await proxyFactoryFactory.deploy()

  // Create Gnosis Safe contract

  const safeProxy = await proxyFactory.createProxy(masterCopy.address, '0x')
  // console.log(safeProxy)
  const transactionReceipt = await safeProxy.wait()
  const proxyAddress = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.proxy
  const safe = await ethers.getContractAt('GnosisSafe', proxyAddress)

  await safe.setup(
    [daoMember1.address, daoMember2.address, daoMember3.address],
    2,
    ethers.constants.AddressZero,
    '0x',
    ethers.constants.AddressZero,
    ethers.constants.AddressZero,
    0,
    ethers.constants.AddressZero
  )

  return safe
}
```

and here i sign a message and try to verify it:

```
      const makerMessageHashBinary = ethers.utils.arrayify(makermessageHash)

      //makers signatur(Gnosis safe)
      const sig1 = safe.connect(daoMember1).approveHash(makerMessageHashBinary)

      const isValidSignature = await safe.isValidSignature(makerMessageHashBinary, sig1)
```

but the problem is :

```
Property 'isValidSignature' does not exist on type 'GnosisSafe'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you are looking for is `checkNSignatures()` from what I could tell, the Safe contract does not implement the isValidSignature() function but rather it is defined in an interface which is used to call back to a contract to [verify a signature](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/345b6e779ee9bf26b1ae25851c46c54781fe527a/contracts/Safe.sol#L315).

Here is the code snippet which might be able to help you out

https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/Safe.sol#L274

Here is the documentation as well on pre approved hashs
https://docs.safe.global/learn/safe-core/safe-core-protocol/signatures#pre-validated-signatures